# console.log is returning the function instead of returning interger

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class TransitionComp extends Component{


      Duration = ()=>{
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(3000))
    }


    render(){
        console.log(this.Duration)
        return(

        )
    }
}
```

The console is returning

```
ƒ () {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(3000));
        }
```

instead of an integer. If I don't use "this", Duration will become undefined.

Comment: try **calling** the function ... i.e. ... `console.log(this.Duration())` - though `Math.random() * Math.floor(3000)` won't return an **integer** ... I think you meant `Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000)`

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to invoke the function is:

```
console.log(this.Duration());
```